# AWS Lambda: How do I connect to a service that uses IP whitelisting from AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-lambda, proxy

We're working with a third-party web service that only allows connections
from whitelisted IP addresses. So far, we've provisioned AWS Elastic IPs for
our EC2 instances and had those IP addresses whitelisted by the provider.

As we start to migrate parts of our application workload to AWS Lambda, how
should we deal with this? I'm envisioning we may have to setup some sort of a proxy
server, but I'm unsure if AWS provides a turnkey solution or whether we'll need to
hack together something with SSH forwarding / SOCKS proxy via an EC2 instance, or
some other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you should use VPC configuration within your Lambda, configuring it within private subnets.

Once it is in these subnets it will only be able to communicate outbound using a NAT. Create either a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) (with an [EIP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) attached to it), then configure your route tables for the subnet(s) the Lambda is in to use this (for high availability use one per AZ).

As each of these NATs has an EIP attached these IP addresses can now be given for whitelisting, this approach allows only your resources to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your Lambda function associated with a VPC, it can then connects via an Elastic Network Interface (ENI). It is possible to attach an EIP to an ENI. OR Static IP of NAT Gateway associated with the VPC.

Comment: This is not recommended. While it is possible to attach a Public IP address to an ENI, which would give the Lambda function access to the Internet (if connected to a public subnet), the AWS Lambda service will create/destroy the ENI connections based upon the number of concurrent Lambda functions being executed. Thus, there is no guarantee that the ENI will continue to be available. The correct method is to attach the Lambda function to a private subnet, and then use a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance with an associated Elastic IP address.